# How to use async/await with file system module

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I use the async/await syntax with`fs.unlink()` to delete a file with the given path.

Comment: `unlinkSync` blocks so you don't need to use async/await with it.

Comment: You can use [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to turn `unlink` (or any other error-first-callback-last function) into a promise that's awaitable.

Comment: `fs.unlinkSync` is synchronous, as the name implies so there is no need for `async/await`. Why are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "promisefy" all callback style functions!

```
// promisefy this:
fs.unlink('path/file.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('path/file.txt was deleted');
});


// to this:
const unlinkPromise = (path) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.unlink('path/file.txt', (err) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve(path);
  });
  
});

// and then call with await or chain promises
await unlinkPromise('path/file.txt').then((path) => {
    console.log(`${path} was deleted`);
});
```

But as already mentioned, the sync method does not require await, this strategy, I would recommend for promise cascades...

Answer (score 7):

When you use the file system function, use it as a promise-based not a callback-based. You can say `fs.promises.unlink()` instead of saying `fs.unlink()`, but keep in mind that this promise built-in functions were added at Node.js Version 10. So, if you are using an older version, this won't work!
To use it in your code, you may do this:

```
await fs.promises.unlink(yourPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need await.

`fs.unlink(path, callback)`

You create a callback

Assuming that 'path/file.txt' is a regular file.

```
fs.unlink('path/file.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('path/file.txt was deleted');
});
```

The asynchronous one is fs.unlink().

The synchronous one is fs.unlinkSync().

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback

Comment: i dont want to use callbacks though